# Typescript does not see a value set in an await

Tags: typescript

Given the following code. The variable `x` is either undefined or a number and initially undefined. Inside the promise that is await'd `x` is then set to 1.

After the await'd promise, `x` is now 1 but typescript still thinks that it is undefined.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```js
async function test() {
  let x:number | undefined = undefined
  await new Promise(res => {
    x = 1
    res(x)
  })
  if (x) {
    console.log(x)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAQwzgngdgxgBAMwK6wC4EsD2U6oKZioAUAlHAN7BxwA2eqcAHgFxRIC2ARngE5wA+cFABM8CdFDzC4AXiFRR4ycKpwQAdxDoGk9XAAKPTO3Rg8RHgVkA+CquqNZcAIz24lsEUYlVAXx-U6AhwXmSU1NQw2GCYdAB0NJgA5qF+wL7AQA)

Comment: Even if you explicitly define the type as `number | undefined`, TypeScript likes to assume that just because it doesn't see any synchronous code reassigning the variable it must be `undefined` as you originally assigned it. I don't know if this has been reported as a bug, but it probably should be.

Comment: It's not a bug.

Comment: I see, thanks for the link to the GitHub issue you included in your answer, I was looking for something like that but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known limitation in TypeScript's ability to perform [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), which is what normally allows the compiler to narrow the apparent type of a [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) variable upon assignment.  The compiler does cannot track the results of control flow analysis across function boundaries, and it assumes that called functions have no effect on the apparent type of any variables.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for an authoritative description of the issue.

When you write `let x:number | undefined = undefined`, the compiler narrows the apparent type of `x` from `number | undefined` to `undefined`.  Generally speaking the compiler cannot know whether or not the callback `res => { x = 1; res(x) }` ever gets executed, so it is probably correct for the compiler not to realize that `x` is `1`.  However, in order to be type safe, the compiler would have to assume that it *might* be called, and thus revert the type of `x` back to `number | undefined`.  But it does not do this, because to do so would make control flow analysis nearly useless.  TypeScript takes the "optimistic" heuristic solution of assuming function calls have no side effects, which in this case is unfortunately wrong.

---

In your case my suggestion (aside from any runtime refactoring) would either be to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on your declaration of `x` to prevent the initial control flow narrowing to `undefined`:

```
async function test() {
  let x = undefined as number | undefined;
  await new Promise(res => {
    x = 1
    res(x)
  })
  // x is number | undefined here
  if (x) {
    x.toFixed(2); // no error now
  }
}
```

Or you could use a type assertion later to tell the compiler that the value is `1` even though it doesn't realize it:

```
async function test2() {
  let x: number | undefined = undefined;
  await new Promise(res => {
    x = 1
    res(x)
  });
  (x as number | undefined as 1).toFixed(2); // okay
}
```

I don't know of a great way to re-widen `x` itself without a runtime change (`x = x as number | undefined as 1` would work but it has a runtime effect).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2QUxMgCgEoYBvAKBhgBsdkYAPGAXhiQBMc5UId2ZQMCAgC2AIxwAnGAB82ETt17sA3JQEB3YKnq8NMAAqT0I1CBwFJeFgD4y6qk1YBGBzCsgCDIuoC+PqlQ4GC8SCipHADpkdAAxVAY+AgAmIhUYAHoMmHQAa2AwNyhMEHRaSOp0AHNQv3JfcnJQSFhEFAwsXHxk4nsqWnoGAC4hUQlpOQ4uHj4WeUUZ1XVgLR0hHH0jEzMLD1s+iKcYVwj3PFqqfzUqLwEQUfEpWXnp5Tvjomi4hKTU9KycvlCg1GkA)

Comment: Is there a reason to make this "optimistic" assumption and narrow the type even when the type is *explicitly* defined as `number | undefined`?

Comment: Another way would be to remove the explicit assignment to undefined `let x: number | undefined`. That way it's still number or undefined by the time we get to `if (x)` removing the need for the type assertion.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad the optimistic assumption is that function calls do not have side effects; narrowing `x` from `number | undefined` to `undefined` upon the assignment `x = undefined` is not optimistic at all; it's just the way [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) works.  The problem here is not the narrowing, it's the lack of re-widening.

Answer (score 2):

The code that sets x to 1 is in a separate function, and while you and i know that the promise constructor will call that function synchronously, typescript can't make that assumption. There are many cases in javascript where callback functions are called asynchronously, with the simplest being `setTimeout`. The type information says nothing about when the function will be called, so typescript has to assume the code will run asynchronously, which means it doesn't affect `x`'s type after the await.

Since you're resolving the promise to 1 anyway, i'd recommend you change your code to this:

```
let x:number | undefined = undefined
x = await new Promise<number>(res => {
  res(1)
})
```

Now typescript knows we're dealing with a promise that resolves to a number, and since you await the promise and then assign its value to x, typescript knows a number will be assigned to x.